# Getting 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')' while trying to test Redux Toolkit extraReducers

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm fairly new to testing and I'm trying to test a simple React app which uses Redux Toolkit to fetch and render data on page load. So after trying for 3 days I could finally test the `initial state`, and thunk's `pending` state but I am unable to test the `fulfilled` state which includes the data fetched from the api, but I'm getting this error:

```
PhoneListContainer Component › should return fulfilled state

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

      73 |                 state.isLoading = false;
      74 |                 state.isSuccess = true;
    > 75 |                 state.products = action.payload.data;
         |                                                 ^
      76 |                 state.message = action.payload.message;
      77 |             } )
      78 |             .addCase( getProducts.rejected, ( state, action ) => {

      at src/features/product/productSlice.tsx:75:49
      at recipe (node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts:280:20)
```

This is the test file:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import apiCall from '../../features/product/productService';

import productReducer, {
    initialState,
    getProducts,
} from '../../features/product/productSlice';

jest.mock( '../../features/product/productService' );

describe( 'PhoneListContainer Component', () => {

    it( 'should return initial state', () => {
        const nextState = productReducer( undefined, {} );
        expect( nextState ).toBe( initialState );
    } );

    it( 'should return pending state', () => {
        const nextState = productReducer( initialState, getProducts.pending() );
        expect( nextState.isLoading ).toBe( true );
    } );

    it( 'should return fulfilled state', () => {
        const nextState = productReducer( initialState, getProducts.fulfilled() );
        console.log( 'nextState: ', nextState );
        expect( nextState.isLoading ).toBe( false );
        expect( nextState.isSuccess ).toBe( true );
        expect( nextState.products.length ).toBe( 6 );
    } );

} );
```

This is the api call function:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Data } from './productSlice';

const API_URL: string = '/api/phones';

const getAllProducts = async (): Promise<Data> => {
    const response = await axios.get( API_URL );
    return response.data;
};

export default getAllProducts;
```

And this is the productSlice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../../app/store';
import getAllProducts from './productService';
import axios from 'axios';

interface Specifications {
    display: string,
    processor: string,
    frontCam: string,
    rearCam: string,
    ram: string,
    storage: string,
    batteryCapacity: string,
    os: string;
}

export interface Products {
    title: string,
    slug: string,
    description: string,
    color: string,
    price: number,
    image: string,
    specifications: Specifications;
};

export interface Data {
    success: boolean;
    message: string;
    data: Products[] | null;
}

interface ProductState {
    products: Products[] | null,
    isError: boolean;
    isSuccess: boolean;
    isLoading: boolean;
    message: string | undefined;
}

export const initialState: ProductState = {
    products: null,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ''
};

export const getProducts = createAsyncThunk( 'products/getAllProducts', async ( _, thunkAPI ) => {
    try {
        const data = await getAllProducts();
        return data;
    } catch ( error ) {
        if ( axios.isAxiosError( error ) ) {
            const message = ( error.response && error.response?.data && error.response?.data.message ) || error.message || error.toString();
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue( message );
        } else {
            throw new Error( 'Something went wrong, please try again!' );
        }
    }
} );

export const productSlice = createSlice( {
    name: 'products',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: ( builder ) => {
        builder
            .addCase( getProducts.pending, ( state ) => {
                state.isLoading = true;
            } )
            .addCase( getProducts.fulfilled, ( state, action: PayloadAction<Data> ) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.isSuccess = true;
                state.products = action.payload.data;
                state.message = action.payload.message;
            } )
            .addCase( getProducts.rejected, ( state, action ) => {
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.isError = true;
                state.message = action.payload as string;
                state.products = null;
            } );
    }
} );

export const getProductsSelector = ( state: RootState ) => state.products;
export default productSlice.reducer;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the response payload has not got data as a property ? You will have to see what the action.payload is by either running a debugger or logging action.payload

then you will see why it is undefined